# updateProgress() method is not working

Tags: java, javafx

I have following adopted version of code posted on this forum. The code is supposed to download given file from the URL and show download progress. It is able to retrieve file size and prints "Download succeeded". It also does what it is instructed to do on succeeded. However, there is neither download on selected location nor progress indicator shows any progress. It seems that updateProgress() method does nothing. Is it some kind of bug, flaw in my logic, or platform incompatibility? I am using JDK 1.8.0_101 on NetBeans 8.1 on Windows 8.1 64-bit.

Here is the code.

```
public class FileLength extends Application {
BorderPane root;    
String url;
File file;
ProgressIndicator pi;
Stage stage;
public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
{
    stage = primaryStage;
    DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Get File");
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
    {

        public void handle(ActionEvent event)
        {
            FileChooser fileSaver = new FileChooser();
            fileSaver.getExtensionFilters().add(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("ZIP", ".zip"));                

            file = fileSaver.showSaveDialog(stage);
            new Thread(task).start();
        }
    });

    root = new BorderPane();        
    root.setBottom(btn);

    pi = new ProgressIndicator();
    pi.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
    /* why this is not binding? */
    root.setTop(pi);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Download progress");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

private  class DownloadTask extends Task<Void>
{
    protected Void call()
    {
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL("http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/bitcoin/Bitcoin/blockchain/bitcoin_blockchain_170000.zip");
            /* url is for example only */

            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) (url.openConnection());
            long completeFileSize = httpConnection.getContentLength();
            System.out.println("File size:" + completeFileSize );

            InputStream is = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);

            long downloadedFileSize = 0L;
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int n = 0;

            while ((n = is.read(buf, 0, 1024)) >= 0) 
            {                   
                downloadedFileSize += n;
                updateProgress(downloadedFileSize, completeFileSize);
                /* why this is not updating progress?*/
                os.write(buf, 0, n);                   
            }
            is.close();
            os.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }            

        return null;
    }
    protected void succeeded()
    {
        // this executes
        System.out.println("Download succeeded");
        root.getChildren().remove(pi);
    }
    protected void failed()
    {
        System.out.println("Download failed");
    }  
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    launch(args);
} }
```

Comment: Choose a valid URL and everything will be fine.

Comment: Worked fine for me when I replaced it with an appropriate URL. The one you have in the code uses a redirect. I used `http://hgdownload.soe.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg38/bigZips/hg38.fa.gz` (complete human genome from University of California Santa Cruz). Note some URLs might not provide a content size, in which case the progress remains indefinite (content size will be -1, so progress < 0, which is interpreted as indefinite).

Comment: No. Still it did not work. I only get size of the file. There is no download. Neither does the progress indicator indicate the progress. It is a wonder! Had you really compiled and run the code? Did you get the file downloaded?

Comment: I tried it too. With a valid URL it works as expected.

Comment: Yes. It worked for an mp3 song. Probably it was the problem with URL. Thanks for your valuable comment. I am still refining and retesting this code. I shall definitely let you know if any problem arises. Because of unworking URL I was extremely frustrated. Thanks once again.